# How to echo specified data form sql database in php

Tags: php, mysql

I need to print data from **users** table for **username** that is logged in, for example, need to bring HP, attack, defence, gold... I found many answers here and after this I am sure I am gone ask more questions. Please help...

```
<?php
session_start()

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    echo "Welcome {$_SESSION['username']}";
}

require_once 'config.php';

    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass)
    or die('Error connecting to mysql');
mysql_select_db($dbname);

    $query = sprintf("SELECT ID FROM users WHERE UPPER(username) = UPPER('%s')",
            mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']));

    $result = mysql_query($query);
    list($userID) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    echo "Health Points:".$row['HP'];
    echo "Attack:";
    echo "Defence:";
    echo "Gold:";

?>
```

Comment: BTW, are you sure that you're using a case-sensitive collation?

Comment: You are using a variable youve never declared before. Where did you steal this code?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you getting an error? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: This code I copy from http://buildingbrowsergames.com/ and it's free to use, so I didn't stole anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to query for all the information you actually want. So your query should look like this:

```
SELECT HP,Atk,Def,Gold FROM ...
```

This will retrieve the named fields from your database and not just the ID.

Also, you never assign your row, it should read

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

(But see my comment below).

Comment: On an unrelated note, you should probably use prepared statements. There are ways to inject even through `mysql_real_escape_string`. That's one of the reasons the `mysql_` functions are deprecated as a whole.

Comment: Alternatively, you can also use the shorthand `*` instead of typing out all the column names. `SELECT * FROM table` automatically retrieves all columns.

Comment: @Tularis I learned that's bad practice though. If, for instance, your table doesn't have a field named "Atk" and you're trying to retrieve it, there will be a MYSQL error telling you that. But if you use `*`, finding the problem is a lot more difficult.

Comment: I agree it's better to use a full list of columns instead of a wildcard. It's not necessarily bad practice though. And I fully disagree that it's difficult to find the problem; in the first case you get an SQL error, in the other you get a nice `E_NOTICE: undefined index`.

Answer (score 0):

1 - there is missing ; in the first line

2 - try "SELECT * " instead of "SELECT ID"

3 - $row is not defined , try :

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

instead of

```
list($userID) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

check the manual for the difference between mysql_fetch_row and mysql_fetch_assoc

[mysql_fetch_assoc](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc)